# How to get the total count of occurence of a word in a sentence

Tags: java

I am trying to find the total count of occurrence of word in a sentence.
I tried the following code:

```
String str = "This is stackoverflow and you will find great solutions  here.stackoverflowstackoverflow is a large community of talented coders.It hepls you to find solutions for every complex problems.";

    String findStr = "hello World";     
    String[] split=findStr.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
        System.out.println(split[i]);
        String indexWord=split[i];
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;      
        while(lastIndex != -1){

            lastIndex = str.indexOf(indexWord,lastIndex);
            System.out.println(lastIndex);

            if(lastIndex != -1){
                count ++;
                lastIndex += findStr.length();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Count for word "+indexWord+" is : "+count);
    }
```

If I am passing string like "stack solution" ,the string should be split into two(space split) and need to find the no of occurrence of each string in the sentence.The count is perfect if I pass only one word.The code has to match even substrings containing the searched string. 
Eg:-In the sentence "stack" apperars three times,but the count is only 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `lastIndex += findStr.length();` with `lastIndex += indexWord.length();`?

Comment: great.its working fine now.Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: I'll add an answer so this question can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increment `lastIndex` after a match, you mean to increment it by the length of the match (`indexWord`), not the length of the string of input words (`findStr`). Just replace the line

```
lastIndex += findStr.length();
```

with

```
lastIndex += indexWord.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String str = "helloslkhellodjladfjhello";
String findStr = "hello";
int lastIndex = 0;
int count = 0;

while(lastIndex != -1){

lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

 if(lastIndex != -1){
    count ++;
    lastIndex += findStr.length();
 }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map for this as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String value = "This is simple sting with simple have two occurence";

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String w : value.split(" ")) {
            if (!w.equals("")) {

                Integer n = map.get(w);
                n = (n == null) ? 1 : ++n;
                map.put(w, n);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("map" + map);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason of not using the readymade API solution in place.
This can be achieved by using the StringUtils in apache commons-lang have CountMatches method to counts the number of occurrences of one String in another.

E.g.

```
String input = "This is stackoverflow and you will find great solutions  here.stackoverflowstackoverflow is a large community of talented coders.It hepls you to find solutions for every complex problems.";
String findStr = "stackoverflow is";
for (String s : Arrays.asList(findStr.split(" "))) {
         int occurance = StringUtils.countMatches(input, s);
         System.out.println(occurance);
}
```